# Private/Internal Specflow steps

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

Is it possible to have Specflow steps that are private/internal to a C# project?

Our test platform has several projects that need to access steps from each other.  However, we have steps within each project that we don't want to make available to other projects.  We need a way to allow access to some steps within a project, but restrict access to others.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no feature for this.

The binding classes don't need to be public that they can be found. But that doesn't help in your case.

I think the only way you can take is, to split your binding assemblies in more and only use the ones you are allowed to.

Comment: That seems like a defeatist attitude.  I'm researching the possibility of providing an IBindingRegistry implementation to solve this.  I'll provide an answer once I have a working solution.

Comment: Perhaps it was a little bit defeatist. But implementing your own IBindingRegistry is nothing I would suggest everyone. You can adjust nearly everything with your own implementation in SpecFlow, but it is a very steep learning curve. And not everyone is up for that. So I gave a quick, short answer about the current implementation.

Comment: BTW, I would be very interested in your solution. Perhaps we could add such feature to SpecFlow itself. PRs are always welcomed.

Comment: I didn't realize that you worked at TechTalk.  I appreciate your feedback.  If we come up with anything useful we'll see about making a PR.